# HttpClient error for Large Json Object: This instance has already started one or more requests

Tags: c#, httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am getting the following error only when requesting large Json objects.

> This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can
>   only be modified before sending the first request

This error is not present when Json object if about 3 to 4 million records, however when record count reaches 10 million this error is produced. No other requests via this HttpClient is performed when this error is produced.

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyMethod(HttpClient client, MyObject 
query)
{
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(Settings.Default.Uri + @"/cmd", 
query);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return response;
}
```

So I can't figure this out why really large Json results produces this error.

Any direction is appreciated it.

Comment: how that method is being called? What kind of application is that? Looks like when the call is `awaited` control is given back to mainthread, so the application is able to handle next call. I am guessing that HttpClient is Singleton, so it ends up in starting another request too early.

Comment: The connection probably closed and then you tried to open the connection again.  Servers will often automatically close when you try to transfer over 10 million bytes.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if connection closed.  When the connection closes you will see at the TCP transport layer a [FIN].

Comment: Try to increase the maximum request size by configuring your web server.

Comment: Both client ans server are .Net console apps divorced from IIS. The method is called in this fashion:

    var response = await MyMethod (client, query);

I assume the HttpClient is singleton since its only once created in the class and never get disposed by statement such as Using. 

I will monitor the connection by wire shark.

Since this an console app I assume I need to adjust MaxRequestLength in machine.config since I can not find this property in app.config